# Unable to replace implements with extends in eclipse JDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

The bug that I'm currently dealing with requires me to replace implements with extends upon selection of the associated quick fix.

For example:

```java
public class R{

}
class Q implements R{ //error here 

}
```

The quick fix will be to change implements to extends (That's what I am focusing on). But to do this I need to have `TypeDeclaration.SUPERCLASS_TYPE` as a `ChildListPropertyDiscriptor` whereas it's now a `ChildPropertyDiscriptor`. Which makes it unable to be supplied as a parameter to `getListRewrite`.

I want to know if there is any way I can make `TypeDeclaration.SUPERCLASS_TYPE` as a `ChildListPropertyDiscriptor`. Or else some other way exists to do this.

My full code snippet is the following:

```java
TypeDeclaration typeDecl= (TypeDeclaration) selectedNode.getParent();
    {
        ASTRewrite rewrite= ASTRewrite.create(root.getAST());
        ASTNode placeHolder= rewrite.createMoveTarget(selectedNode);
        ListRewrite interfaces= rewrite.getListRewrite(typeDecl, TypeDeclaration.SUPERCLASS_TYPE_PROPERTY);   //problem here
        interfaces.insertFirst(placeHolder, null);

        String label= CorrectionMessages.LocalCorrectionsSubProcessor_implementstoextends_description;
        Image image= JavaPluginImages.get(JavaPluginImages.IMG_CORRECTION_CHANGE);
        ASTRewriteCorrectionProposal proposal= new ASTRewriteCorrectionProposal(label, context.getCompilationUnit(), rewrite, IProposalRelevance.CHANGE_EXTENDS_TO_IMPLEMENTS, image);
        proposals.add(proposal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multi-inheritance so there is only one type for `extends` supported. This explains why `TypeDeclaration.SUPERCLASS_TYPE` is no list and so has no `ChildListPropertyDescriptior` (for possible use with `ListRewrite`).

What you want instead is [`ASTRewrite.set()`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/rewrite/ASTRewrite.html#set-org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode-org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.StructuralPropertyDescriptor-java.lang.Object-org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEditGroup-):

```
rewrite.set(typeDecl, TypeDeclaration.SUPERCLASS_TYPE_PROPERTY, placeHolder, null);
```